# how to set start value as "0" in chartjs?

Tags: charts, chart.js

here is my code. i need to set initial value as "0" in both x and y axis     scales. I have tried latest version scales option.

```
graphOptions = {               
            ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
            scaleShowGridLines: false,    
            tooltipTitleTemplate: "<%= label%>",
            //String - Colour of the grid lines
            scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
            //Number - Width of the grid lines
            scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
            //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
            scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
            //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
            scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
            //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
            bezierCurve: true,
            //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
            bezierCurveTension: 0.4,
            //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
            pointDot: true,
            //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
            pointDotRadius: 4,
            //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
            pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,               
            pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,               
            datasetStroke: true,
            datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
            datasetFill: true,               
            legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
        };
        var LineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(graphData, graphOptions);
   }
```

Comment: I found that putting an extra zero in the data list without assigning a name does the trick

Answer (score 421, accepted):

For Chart.js 2.*, the option for the scale to begin at zero is listed under the [configuration options of the linear scale](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-linear-scale). This is used for numerical data, which should most probably be the case for your y-axis. So, you need to use this:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

A sample line chart is also available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/742zut83/29/) where the option is used for the y-axis. If your numerical data is on the x-axis, use `xAxes` instead of `yAxes`. Note that an array (and plural) is used for `yAxes` (or `xAxes`), because you may as well have multiple axes.

Comment: @SuganthanRaj You are welcome! Just make sure that you consult the docs for Chart.js 2.0. A lot have changed from the 1.0 version and most examples online apply to the 1.0 version. ;)

Comment: @SuganthanRaj For instance, the `scaleShowVerticalLines` is not valid for 2.0. Or the tooltip template. Options, in general, follow a hierarchical approach in 2.0.

Comment: This answer is outdated, the Wouter Debie's answer bellow works for me.

Answer (score 76):

It's now (5 years later and version 3.x) a bit different

```
options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
```

see: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/#creating-a-chart

Comment: Thanks for the Chart.js 3 solution.

Answer (score 11):

If you need use it as a default configuration, just place `min: 0` inside the node `defaults.scale.ticks`, as follows:

```
defaults: {
  global: {...},
  scale: {
    ...
    ticks: { min: 0 },
  }
},
```

Reference: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

Answer (score 5):

Please add this option:

```
//Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
scaleBeginAtZero : true,
```

*(Reference: [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options))*

**N.B:** The original solution I posted was for Highcharts, if you are not using Highcharts then please remove the tag to avoid confusion

Comment: its not working . i am using latest version of chartjs v2.1

Comment: @wmash I need to start the chart from the predefined value. Do you know how to do this? I tried to put this option to both true and false, but it does not work.

Comment: this is incorrect and could / should be deleted. `beginAtZero: true` is what you need