# Jquery Bargraph not Loading properly

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am using Bar graph to load my mysql data on Dashboard. Issue is when i am adding qc_point =100, It is starting directly from 100 and not showing graph of the same user. It should start with 0.

**Dashboard :-**

[image]

**Database :-**

[image]

Data.php :-

```
//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT qc_user, sum(qc_point) as qc_point FROM qc group by qc_user ORDER BY qc_user");


//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

**app.js :-**

```
method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var qc_user = [];
            var qc_point = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                qc_user.push(data[i].qc_user);
                qc_point.push(data[i].qc_point);
            }



            var chartdata = {
                labels: qc_user,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Technical',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: qc_point
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set start value as "0" in chartjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922518/how-to-set-start-value-as-0-in-chartjs)

Comment: It *looks* like you're using Chart.js - can you specify which library you're using?  (if it's is chart.js then add [chart.js] tag)

Comment: It is chart.js. where should i add this tag ? ([chart.js] tag) –)

Comment: It is not fixed yet.

Comment: Add the tag to the question tags, where you added [php] [mysql] (which are not actually relevant to the question being asked).

Comment: It is dropped. Can you help to fix this. I don't get idea from this how to set start value as "0" in chartjs?

Comment: From the linked answer: `options: { scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero:true } }] } }` add directly after your `data:chartdata` (with a comma of course)

Comment: It is worked. Now, what is the option to take the highest point graph at first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your chartjs option:

```
options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```